# Why is my ArrayList throwing a "PSCustomObject doesn't contain a method for 'foreach'" error when the ArrayList contains <= 1 item, & only in PS 5?

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist, powershell-5.0

I have the following script I wrote using PowerShell 5 that utilizes the Active Directory and [Join-Object](https://github.com/ili101/Join-Object) PowerShell modules to get a list of all AD Groups and their users (along with some additional properties per user like their manager and title):

```bsh
$ADGroupsList = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object DistinguishedName,CN,GroupCategory,Description | Sort-Object CN)

#I'm using an ArrayList here so that later on I can use the .Add() method to avoid costly += operations.
$ADUsersList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
$ADUsersList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$Record = [ordered] @{
    "Group Name" = ""
    "Employee Name" = ""
    "Title"= ""
    "Manager" = ""
}

foreach ($Group in $ADGroupsList) {
        $ArrayofMembers = @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "user" })
    
    #Loop through each member in the list of members from above
    foreach ($Member in $ArrayofMembers) {
        #Get detailed user info about the current user like title and manager that aren't available from Get-ADGroupMember
        $User = @(Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Properties name,title,manager | Select-Object Name, Title, @{Label="Manager";Expression={(Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $Member -Properties Manager).Manager).Name}})
        
        #Specifies what values to apply to each property of the $Record object
        $Record."Group Name" = $Group.CN
        $Record."Employee Name" = $Member.Name
        $Record."Title" = $User.Title
        $Record."Manager" = $User.Manager

        #Put all the stored information above in a 'copy' record
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record

        #Add that copy to the existing data in the ADUsersList object
        [void]$ADUsersList.Add($objRecord)
    }

    #Using Join-Object here to enable me to use SQL-like JOINs
    Join-Object -Left $ADUsersList -Right $ADGroupsList -LeftJoinProperty "Group Name" -RightJoinProperty "CN" -Type AllInLeft -LeftMultiMode DuplicateLines -RightMultiMode DuplicateLines -ExcludeRightProperties DistinguishedName | Export-Csv ("C:\ADReports\" + $Group.CN + " Report.csv") -NoTypeInformation

    $ADUsersList.Clear()

}
```

Here's the output I expect (columns may be out of order, but column ordering isn't important):

[image: Desired output of $ADUsersList contents combined with $ADGroupsList contents]

My code works great for most groups, but for groups that have only one member (or none), I get an error:

```bsh
Join-Object : Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'ForEach'.
At C:\GetADGroups&Users.ps1:54 char:5
+     Join-Object -Left $ADUsersList -Right $ADGroupsList -LeftJoinProp ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ForEach:String) [Join-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Join-Object
```

At first, I thought it was because I read arrays/arraylists with one entry get turned into scalars. But a knee-jerk wrapping of every object I can think of in `@()` didn't resolve the issue. In fact, if I wrap the `$objRecord` assignment (`New-Object PSObject -property $Record`) in `@()` to convert it to an array, it writes the *Member Properties* of `$ADUsersList` to the Join-Object line instead of the contents of `$ADUsersList`, resulting in this:

[image: CSV output of $ADUsersList properties combined with $ADGroupsList contents]

Is there somewhere I've missed an array/arraylist getting converted to a scalar? Why is the code above throwing an error for groups with <= 1 entries?

Compounding my curiosity, PowerShell 7 (possibly 6, too) doesn't seem to care about this issue; it doesn't throw the error at all (instead it just outputs the appropriate single-value/blank CSV). Normally I'd just wipe my hands and say PS 7 is required, but I'd like to get this working in PowerShell 5, or at least understand what is causing the issue.

Googling led me to several related articles & questions, including:

- [Method Invocation .Foreach failed, System.Object doesn't contain a method named 'foreach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738206/;) this one's specific to PowerShell v2 (I'm running v5)
- [Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911366/;) this one seems only tangentially related. Incidentally it's where I read that arrays with one item output as scalars, as I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear that scalars lack the `.ForEach()` & `.Where()` methods in 5.1.  The additional of the methods is probably just an enhancement newer version, certainly 7 not sure about 6.  I'm sure that's documented somewhere.

I can't really test your code but it doesn't look like there's anywhere that could be flipping to a scalar.  To help guarantee ArrayList collections through out you can type constrain the variables like `[Collections.ArrayList]$Var = @()`  This may end up being more practical than hunting for an implementing `@()` throughout.

Something that stands out is the error seems to come from `Join-Object` I only found a single invocation of `.ForEach()` on line 820 of `Join-Object.ps1`  My guess is it's this line or similar elsewhere in the module combined with the 5.1 runtime environment.

If you can manually modify that to a traditional `| ForEach-Object {...}` might be telling.  And/or you can wrap `$result` like `@($Result)` right before the `.ForEach()` is invoked.

Really interested to see what you come up with.  I see you've already posted an issue with the author.  Please post back if you get a reply.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, the current open issue with the author on GitHub is about support in Join-Object for ArrayLists (and they've already updated the code to support it, though the PSGallery entry hasn't been updated to reflect that change). I'll check for info on where that was specifically added as well as look into modifying the Join-Object ps1 file on my local machine in VS Code.

Comment: After some searching, it looks like the single-value array issue was [a regression in v5](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2208) that was not fixed until [PowerShell Core/6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3170). So it indeed looks to be purely specific to v5. Not 100% on that, since the PRs and underlying code are outside my wheelhouse.

Comment: I think we already verified that ; ). My hope, for your purposes was the simple change to avoid `.ForEach()` in the `Join-Object` code would side-step the issue.  While I understand you may not want to modify someone else's stuff.  BTW, I realize moving away from 5.1 may not be as straight forward as MS suggests.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to pin down a specific PR or change that referenced fixing the issue. What was mildly interesting was that it apparently wasn't an issue in v4. Anyway, I hope to try `| ForEach-Object {...}` today. Will let you know as soon as I can test that.

Comment: After changing line 820 in Join-Object to `@($Result) | ForEach-Object { $_ }`, I still got the same error. Then I instead went back and changed my own code from `ForEach ($Group in $ADGroupsList) {}` to `$ADGroupsList | ForEach-Object {}` (updating each `$Group` instance to `$_`), and still got the same issue :-/

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is solely in the ps1 file. I think you probably would have to go through the function declarations in the PSM1 file(s).  I kind of hinted that earlier, sorry I wasn't more explicit.

Comment: I just checked the PSM file and unfortunately it only has the following contents: `Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot\*.ps1" -Exclude 'Class.ps1', 'Install.ps1' | ForEach-Object { . $_.FullName }` (and a commented-out line above).